# Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: It must be an executable file: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTEJENKINSTESTING/drivers/chromedriverAugust2023.exe

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, pom.xml

Hi I have a framework and it runs well with maven command in my windows PC, i am trying to run the same using Jenkins on a linux but getting this error.

I tried a lot of things but cannot fix it...I also tried with and without .exe and with linux chrome driver

JENKINS OUTPUT:

12-09-2023 19:33:59 BaseTest:108:[INFO] - Quitting Driver
12-09-2023 19:33:59 BaseTest:109:[INFO] - ===============================================
[ERROR] Tests run: 64, Failures: 32, Errors: 0, Skipped: 32, Time elapsed: 1.668 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] setUpDriver(TestCases.RTETests.RTEAPIAndUITests.RTEAPISportsPagesTests.RTEAPISportsResultsTests)  Time elapsed: 0.902 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: It must be an executable file: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTEJENKINSTESTING/drivers/chromedriverAugust2023.exe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVtEd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMh8V.png)

I am trying to make it run on the linux server as well.

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're encountering indicates that Jenkins is trying to use an executable file named "chromedriverAugust2023.exe," but it expects an executable that is compatible with Linux, not a Windows executable with a .exe extension.

Here are some steps you can take to resolve this issue:

1. **Use the Appropriate Linux-Compatible WebDriver:**
   Ensure that you have downloaded the Linux-compatible version of ChromeDriver and placed it in the correct directory on your Linux server. You should not be using the .exe file on Linux. You can download the appropriate ChromeDriver for Linux from the official ChromeDriver website.
2. **Update the WebDriver Path in Your Test Code:**
   Make sure that your test framework (e.g., Selenium) is configured to use the correct path for the ChromeDriver executable on your Linux server. You may need to update the code that sets up the WebDriver to point to the Linux-compatible ChromeDriver location.
3. **Check Jenkins Configuration:**
   In your Jenkins job configuration, ensure that you are specifying the correct path to the Linux-compatible ChromeDriver. The path should be valid on the Linux machine where Jenkins is running.
4. **File Permissions:**
   Confirm that the ChromeDriver executable on your Linux server has the necessary executable permissions. You can use the `chmod` command to adjust the file permissions if needed.
5. **Test Locally on Linux:**
   Before integrating with Jenkins, try running your tests locally on the Linux server to ensure that they work as expected.
6. **Environment Variables:**
   Check if there are any environment variables or system properties that need to be set for your tests to run correctly on Linux. These settings might differ from your Windows environment.
7. **Jenkins Workspace:**
   Ensure that the path to the ChromeDriver executable matches the workspace directory specified in your Jenkins job configuration.

Once you've addressed these points and configured your Jenkins job correctly to use the Linux-compatible ChromeDriver, your tests should run without issues on the Linux server. If you encounter further problems, please provide more details about your setup and configuration for more specific guidance.